# Turn on Windows Virtual Keyboard (Tabtip.exe) in email and numeric mode

Tags: c#, wpf, virtual-keyboard

I have developed a **WPF Application** using **Webbrowser (System.Windows.Browser)**, I have loaded local html file with input controls of type **email, number, tel** etc.

```
<input type="email" />
<input type="number" />
```

The virtual keyboard changes to email, number while the **page is loaded over Internet Explorer** but not over my developed WPF Webbrowser Application.